# Firebase Storage TypeScript error: Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Promise<UploadResult>'

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I'm trying to implement a Vue Composable that uploads files to Firebase storage.

I am using the modular Firebase version 9 and implementing it by copying [this example in their docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress).

But that example uses plain JavaScript, and I want to implement it in TypeScript.

In my code below `.on` is throwing a TypeScript error that says `Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Promise<UploadResult>'.`

How to solve this?

```
import { projectStorage } from "@/firebase/config";
import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue";
import { ref as storageRef, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const useStorage = (file: File) => {
  watchEffect(() => {
    // references
    const storageReference = storageRef(projectStorage, "images/" + file.name);
    // upload file
    const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageReference, file);
    // upload progress
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", (snapshot: any) => {
      console.log(snapshot);
    });
  });
};
export default useStorage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `uploadBytesResumable()` instead of `uploadBytes()` if you need to monitor upload progress.

`uploadBytes()` return a Promise containing an [UploadResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadresult) and uploads are not resumable. With `uploadBytesResumable()`, the upload can be paused and resumed, and exposes progress updates.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress).

```
import { ref as storageRef, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

const storageReference = storageRef(projectStorage, "images/" + file.name);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageReference, file);

uploadTask.on("state_changed", (snapshot: any) => {
  console.log(snapshot);
});
```